# What is the most modern and idiomatic way to define a type safe "byte" ( as in 8 bits ) type in C++?

Tags: c++, types, type-safety

I want to define a `byte` type in my C++ program, basically an `unsigned char` what is the most idiomatic way to go about doing this?

I want to define a `byte` type to abstract away the different representations and make it possible to create typesafe arrays of this new `byte` ( 8 bit ) type that is backed by an `unsigned char` for a bit manipulation library I am working on for a very specific use case of a program I am creating. I want it to be very *explicit* that this is an 8 bit byte specific to the domain of my program and that is is not subject to the varying implementations based on platform or compiler.

Answer (score 4):

`char`, `unsigned char`, or `signed char` are all one byte; `std::uint8_t` (from `<cstdint>`) is an 8-bit byte (a signed variant exists too). This last one only exists on systems that do have 8-bit bytes. There is also `std::uint_least8_t` (from the same header), which has *at least* 8 bits and `std::uint_fast8_t`, which has at least 8 bits and is supposed to be the most efficient one.

Comment: Surely `char` can be more than 8 bits wide according to the standard

Comment: yes I know this, I want to know what the best way to declare a `type` of `byte` to abstract this away! your edit still does not answer my question.

Comment: @Jarrod to abstract *what* away? If you want an 8bit byte, that is already abstracted away: `std::uint8_t`. There is no point in abstracting your abstractions.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in that case, a byte would also be more than 8 bits wide.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, my impression is that Jarrod takes "byte" to mean an 8 bit type.

Comment: @Jarrod - On platforms without a `uint8_t` you probably cannot get any 8-bit datatype anyway. And you will have lots of other problems that cannot be abstracted away.

Comment: @Jarrod then I have no idea what the question is. "I want it to be very explicit that this is an 8 bit byte specific to the domain of my program." There's very little that can be more explicit about this than `std::uint8_t`. Maybe something like `typedef std::uint8_t this_is_an_8_bit_byte_specific_to_the_domain_of_my_program;` is more explicit, but I see no point in doing it.

Comment: @BoPersson - **by definition**, a platform without a `uint8_t` doesn't have any 8-bit data type. A conforming implementation must provide it if it exists and must not if it doesn't.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Not if the compiler is not C++11 / C99 compliant. My approach would be `typedef unsigned char byte; static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "Unsupported platform");`

Comment: @David that's not the most modern way! ;)

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Is it not? :) I thought the use of `static_assert` made it *modern* :P

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - if your compiler doesn't support C99 (note the **99**, i.e., it's been the standard for over ten years) you should change compilers.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I guess it depends on the platform. I don't know if VisualStudio has C99 support, for example.

Answer (score 2):

The most idiomatic way is to just use `signed char` or `unsigned char`. You can use typedef if you want to call it `byte` or if you need it to be strongly typed you could use BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF.

If you need it to be exactly 8 bits, you can use `uint8_t` from `<cstdint>` but it is not guaranteed to exist on all platforms.

Comment: `unint8_t` will exist on the platforms I am specifically concerned about.

Comment: Then go ahead and use it. It will most likely be a typedef for `unsigned char` so if you want type-safety you have to use something like BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this is one of the most irritating "features" in C++ for me.

Yes, you can use `std::uint8_t` or `unsigned char`, which on most systems the former will be the `typedef` of the latter.

But... This is not type safe, as `typedef` will not create a new type. And commitee refused to add a "strong typedef" to the standard.

consider

```
void foo (std::uint8_t);
void foo (unsigned char); // ups...
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here. If you want to force an 8 bit byte, then use `uint8_t`. If you want to use a byte, whatever size that happens to be, use `char`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I want to use both and with different symantics. `char` is not `int8`, they are different types (not in c++ though).

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the uint8_t approach. The way I see it is, if a platform does not have an 8 bit type (in which case my code will not function on that platform), then I don't want it to be running anyways, because I would end up with unexpected behaviour due to the fact that I am processing data with the assumption that it is 8 bits, when in fact it is not. So I don't see why you should use unsigned char, assume it is 8 bits, and then perform all your calculations based on that assumption. It's just asking for trouble in my opinion.